# How to handle total count of MPI tasks

Tags: c, cluster-computing, openmpi

I have a MPI C programm and I need to execute it on 2 nodes, 2 processors on each node, and after completion of MPI, the script ahs to start two more copies of itself. Total count of MPI tasks have to be equal 100. I do it on cluster. I am not sure how to handle its count.

my laboratory task:
Run a task that executes the MPI program on 2 nodes with 2 processors on each node and after the MPI program completes, it starts two more copies of itself. A total of 100 MPI tasks should run. In parallel with the MPI tasks, run a task that, after the completion of all your MPI programs, will analyze the statistics on which nodes and how many MPI processes have been executed. The results of the MPI programs are created in the home directory.

I have next script, but it seems wrong:

```
#PBS -N Ibrahimov_lab2                                                                                                                                                                                           
#PBS -l walltime=00:02:00,nodes=2:ppn=2 
TOTAL_TASKS=100

ml icc
ml openmpi

mpirun hello

for ((i=1; i<TOTAL_TASKS; i++))
do
  qsub script.sh
done
```